# JavaFX ToggleButton Shadow

Tags: java, javafx

Hello Fellow StackOverflow Users, this is my first post/question and hopefully i'm not violating any rules/ect.

Unfortunately I am unable to post a picture, but I will put this here for a reference.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOPAL.jpg (Before Button Click)

OT: On the picture above, I am attempting to make the button's background completely transparent besides the text.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/duocU.jpg (After Button Click)

Everything works out until I click the button then shadows appear on the side.

Here is what I have tried...

CSS

```
.toggle-button {
    -fx-text-fill: black;
    -fx-base: transparent;
    -fx-background: transparent;
    -fx-focus-color: transparent;
    -fx-border-color: transparent;
    -fx-effect: null;
}

.toggle-button:selected {
    -fx-text-fill: black;
    -fx-base: transparent;
    -fx-background: transparent;
    -fx-focus-color: transparent;
    -fx-border-color: transparent;
    -fx-effect: null;
}
```

The java code is just a plain simple application with a ToggleButton.

Special Thanks in Advance!
- Bart

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't recommend modifing the main color palette (`-fx-base` and others) for just one control. This makes sense if you're trying to style all of them.

Looking at how is defined in `modena.css`:

```
.toggle-button {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-shadow-highlight-color, -fx-outer-border, 
        -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color;
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-text-base-color;
}
.toggle-button:selected {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-shadow-highlight-color,
        linear-gradient(to bottom, derive(-fx-outer-border, -20%), ...),
        linear-gradient(to bottom, derive(-fx-color, -22%) 0%, ...);
}
.toggle-button:selected:focused {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-focus-color, 
        linear-gradient(to bottom, derive(-fx-color, -22%) 0%, ...),
        -fx-faint-focus-color, linear-gradient(to bottom, derive(-fx-color, -22%) 0%, ...);
}
```

you will need to change all of them: `-fx-shadow-highlight-color`, `-fx-outer-border`,...

Instead, I'll just override the style of the toggle button with your requirements:

```
.toggle-button,
.toggle-button:focused,
.toggle-button:selected,
.toggle-button:selected:focused {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
}
```

**NOTE** I've edited my answer since, as @eckig suggests, it's redundant to apply the same color to the different comma separated values.

Comment: It is redundant to state 3 or 4 times 'transparent'. You only use a comma separated list of colors if you want multiple colors. And modifying the base colors is a great idea of him. Color derivation is one of the greatest features of JavaFX CSS!

Comment: If you want to override the default styling, you need to override all of the comma separated list of colors. On the contrary, with your approach, you have to change one by one all of the colors in the palette that are involved in the styling. Both work, for sure, it depends on which is better in each situation...

Comment: I thought the different, but re-tested it: Assigning just `-fx-background-color: transparent;`removes all background colors. And this is just working as expected. The assignment `-fx-background-color: xyz;` Is a complete CSS value assignment, replacing all assignments with lesser precedence.

Comment: @eckig Yes, you're right, I'll edit my answer, since it makes it even simpler.

Comment: I guess what you meant is when you override a CSS rule that modifies a series of values. Example: If you modify/override the rule for the buttons background-insets, you should do it for all background colors.

Comment: Yes, these properties are meant for theming options, as they are applied somehow to all the controls. If you apply some changes, these should be addressed in the `.root` style class. It doesn't really make sense to me going into all the troubles to modify them just to style some button.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the button-like optics completely, I would suggest you to remove all existing styles and add your own style class as the only style class:

```
ToggleButton toggleButton = new ToggleButton("Login");
toggleButton.getStyleClass().setAll("my-custom-button");
```

Now you can apply only the styles you need:

```
.my-custom-button {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Special Thanks to both of you, Jose & Eckig. I managed to edit my code with both your suggestions and it fixed the issue right away!

Here is a reference for anyone in the future.

Button Code

```
ToggleButton button= new ToggleButton("Login");
button.getStyleClass().add("custom");
```

CSS

```
.custom,
    custom:selected {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this CSS:

```
.toggle-button {
    -fx-text-fill: black;
    -fx-base: transparent;
    -fx-background: transparent;
    -fx-focus-color: transparent;
    -fx-border-color: transparent;
    -fx-effect: null;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box ,rgba(0,0,0,10) , 20, 0.0 , 0 , 1);
}

.toggle-button:selected {
    -fx-text-fill: black;
    -fx-base: transparent;
    -fx-background: transparent;
    -fx-focus-color: transparent;
    -fx-border-color: transparent;
    -fx-effect: null;
}
```